# How do I stop movement from being mirrored on the X and Y axis with Unity & Kinect?

Tags: unity, kinect

I have made a scene and avatar in the scene, put all of the correct joints on the Open NI Skeleton, but the outcome is not only mirrored on the x-axis, it is also on the y-axis.

So, when I lift my arms, the avatar's arms move downward. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you include any code that shows how you are mapping the tracker output to the model?